# receive http response with content length and chunked encoding headers together

Tags: tomcat, nginx, gwt, chunked-encoding, content-length

We have web application and most our clients visit our web page properly. But **each** client who is using **`td-lte`** network service of `Irancell` company has problem to load `CSS` or 'JS' static files of our web application resources. 
They are see this error in console of their browsers (I can't post image):

[image: error on console of chrome browser on windows]

[image: response header]

And this problem occur in `Chrome`, `FireFox` and `SamSung` browsers and in `Windows`, `Linux`, `Mac` and `Android` OS.

We use [`nginx`](https://nginx.org/en/) on `CentOS` as Web Server and two `tomcat` on `CentOS` as application servers. All of these servers are virtual machine. Also we use [`Cloudflare`](https://www.cloudflare.com/) for security.
Also we use `GWT` framework for our web application.

Comment: What is the question here? This reads more like a bug report...

Comment: Who do I report to? (Irancell? nginx? Cloudflear?)